# assign sql results with same name to array

Tags: php, sql

I have a general question regarding the assigning of sql results to a arrays. 
What should I do when I want to assign some results to an array and when I am joining two or more tables and some columns got the same name:

Example:

```
$sqlExample = "select u.first_name, o.first_name from tbl_user u join tbl_owner o on u.user_id = o.user_id where u.user_id = $user_id;";
       ...
$userFirstName[$var] = $result['first_name'];
$ownerFirstName[$var] =
```

I know, that this is not a great example, but I hope that you are understanding my question..
I thought I could use something like the table prefix for the results, but it didn't worked.

-- Just an example not the code I am using/

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: for example: `select i.first_name uFirst_name, o.first_name oFirstname,...`

Comment: @Jan simple use alias field name

Comment: Hi Jay, yes I know - just an example. In my project I am using something like: $stmt = $db->prepare('update first_name set name = ? where id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('si',$name,$id);
$stmt->execute();

Answer (score 2):

Alias your columns in the results:

```
select u.first_name as user_first_name, o.first_name as owner_first_name from ...
```

Then use those aliases in your code:

```
$userFirstName[$var] = $result['user_first_name'];
$ownerFirstName[$var] = $result['owner_first_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlExample = "SELECT
  u.first_name AS user_first_name,
  o.first_name AS owner_first_name
FROM tbl_user u
  JOIN tbl_owner o ON u.user_id = o.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = $user_id";

$result['user_first_name'];
$result['owner_first_name'];
```